# Push ViewController with coder aDecoder: NSCoder

Tags: ios, swift, nscoder

I'm trying to push a view controller using:

`var vc2 = ViewController2()`

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: false`)

but in my second view controller, I'm have:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

But I get the error `Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call` in the first ViewController. What goes in the parenthesis in the first view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can fix this issue:

The easy way, just call the function passing nil to the parameters:

```
var vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

The best way, create convenience initializers in your class:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }
    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }
    convenience override init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
    }
}
```

and now you can call:

```
var vc2 = ViewController2()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    convenience init () {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Now you can call `ViewController2()`